# Get Referenced Assemblies in F#

Tags: assembly, f#, lambda

I am trying to load the referenced Assemblies through an iteration.
I load the assembly, and get the referenced assemblies by getRefs. getRefs does not have any input parameters so it should be val getRefs: Assembly->AssemblyName[], but thinks it is unit->AssemblyName[], 
any ideas?

```
let getreffiles (name:string) =
     let loadAssembly (name:string)=  
         Assembly.Load(name)  
     let getRefs (assembly:Assembly)=  
        assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies  
     //Get the referenced assembly list and print the full name to console  
     name  
     |>loadAssembly  
     |>getRefs   
     |>List.iter (fun s -> 
           printfn "Referenced Assembly name %s  types" s.FullName);;
```

```
Type mismatch. Expecting a (unit -> AssemblyName []) -> 'a  but given a  'b list -> unit     
The type 'unit -> AssemblyName []' does not match the type ''a list'    
C:\Users\Ebru\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Find\GetAssembly.fs
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to execute the method GetReferencedAssemblies, by adding a () at the end.  Without adding that "()", you're simply returning a reference to the function instead of returning the results of the function.  Also, change List.iter to Array.iter.  GetReferencedAssemblies returns and array, not a list.

```
let getreffiles (name:string) =
     let loadAssembly (name:string)=  
         Assembly.Load(name)  
     let getRefs (assembly:Assembly)=  
        assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()
     //Get the referenced assembly list and print the full name to console  
     name  
     |>loadAssembly  
     |>getRefs   
     |> Array.iter (fun s -> 
           printfn "Referenced Assembly name %s  types" s.FullName);;
```

Answer (score 0):

If a function has no inputs its input is of type 'unit.'  This is similar to void in C, except the function parameter is explicit.